# Can anyone identify this chip? 14-pin DIP on car amplifier board - top marking L074D 039

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, identification, automotive

Is on a car amplifier board. 2 of them. 1 for each channel?

[image: photo of unknown IC on PCB]

Comment: There exists a TL074 IC.

Comment: Most certainly an amp. Showing back side of PCB would be helpful to us.